# Group with a special generating set

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

Let $G$ be a group such that:

1) $G$ can be generated by a finite set of elements of infinite order.

2) In $G$ there is a subgroup $H$ such that $H$ is a free group and its index $|G:H|$ in $G$ is finite.

For instance, $G=\left ( \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \right )\ast\left ( \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \right )$ (but $\left ( \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \right )\ast\left ( \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \right )$ does not satisfy the first condition).

Is there any description of such type of groups?

Comment: It all depends on your background. Do you know what a graph of groups is? If you do, there is a relatively simple description generalizing the examples you have. If you do not know graphs of groups, do you know about amalgamated free products and HNN extensions?

Comment: @MoisheCohen I do know what a graph of groups is.

Comment: Then the answer is: The fundamental group of a nontrivial finite connected graph of groups whose vertex groups are finite.

Comment: @MoisheCohen I do not understand why such groups can be generated by elements of infinite order.

Comment: If $G$ is such a group and $H< G$ is a finite index free subgroup then every coset $Hg$ contains an infinite order element.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Is it so obvious? $G=\left \langle a,b|a^2,b^2 \right \rangle$, and let $H$ be $\left \langle ab \right \rangle\simeq \mathbb{Z}$, then $G = H\sqcup Ha$.

Comment: Yes you are right, one has to exclude the case of 2-ended groups. To prove the claim about cosets you consider a simplicial tree $T$, a hyperbolic automorphism $h$ of $T$ and an elliptic automorphism $g$ of $T$, such that $gA\cap A$ is finite, where $A$ is the axis of $h$. Then show that $gh^n$ is hyperbolic for large $n$.  (Play "ping-pong".)

Comment: @MoisheCohen I beleive that I got it, thank you

Comment: Good. The right statement is then: Iff $G$ is the fundamental group of a nontrivial finite graph of finite groups and $G$ does not map onto $Z_2 * Z_2$ with finite kernel.